# Collapsed functions after opening script

Tags: rstudio

Is there a way to show functions collapsed, after opening a script in RStudio?

I like to just open the part of my script, which I manipulate and until now, I close collapse the other brackets manually and would like to automate that.

Comment: Thank you for the question I always wondered this

Comment: I don't think there's a way to do this.  You could make a request that this be added to the rstudioapi package.

Comment: How would I do that?